# What is the fee cost of a Loki blink instant transaction and does this fee get burned?

Tags: transaction-fees, monero-forks, loki, loki-blink

Loki just released instant transactions for a cryptonote coin. What is the transaction fee and does this fee get burned when making a loki blink transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loki blink transactions are 5x the fee minimum fee of 0.04 which equals to 0.2 loki fee to do a blink transaction. 4/5 of that fee is burned and the 1/5 is paid out to miners.

> The base fee is *slightly* higher than 0.04; it's 0.04 plus a small
>   per-byte amount.  The cli wallet has a "fee" command that can spit out
>   the details along with a typical tx estimate:
>
> Current fee is 0.000000192 loki per byte + 0.020000000 loki per output
>   Current blink fee is 0.000000960 loki per byte + 0.100000000 loki per
>   output Estimated typical small transaction fees: 0.040480000
>   (unimportant), 0.202400000 (normal), 1.012000000 (elevated),
>   5.060000000 (priority), 0.202400000 (blink)

Eventually blink transactions will be on by default making every transaction on the loki network instant.